# Java: What is the case complexity excellent, average and worst of this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I want to know the complexity of this algorithm. In my case both in good, medium and worst is O(n^2)

```
public char getModa(char[] a){
   int ii[] =new int[a.length];
   char[] t= new char[a.length];

   for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
       if(a[j]==a[i]){ 
          ii[i]++;
          t[i]=a[j];
       }
     }
   }
   int cc=0;
   for(int i=0;i<ii.length;i++){
     if(ii[i]>ii[cc]) cc=i;
   }
   return a[cc];
 }
```

Comment: What is the Problem? (First step: have a look how deep the loops are nested)

Comment: I want to know if the complexity excellent, average and worst of this algorithm!

Comment: @MrSmith42 he wrote, that he thinks about O(n^2)

Comment: The number of loop iteration does not depend of the data (only of its size). Why do you refer to `good, medium and worst`?

Comment: @Andremoniy: Sounds if user1960978 is not sure. So there is still the question, what is the concrete question.

Comment: I think this question should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MrSmith42 however, that algorithm I wrote it and it is not a homework assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complexity of all cases (best/average/worst) is `O(n^2)`, the bottle-neck is the double iteration over `(i,j)` in `range([0,a.length),[0,a.length))`.

To clarify why it is indeed `O(n^2)` and not `O(n^3)` as one might think - because the last loop is not 'nested' in side the bottle-neck, so the complexity of the 3 loops is basically `O(n^2+n)`, but since `O(n^2+n) = O(n^2)`, this is the answer.

In fact - there is no variation at all, for the same length arrays - the algorithm has the same number of iterations, regardless of what the input exactly is.

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the nested for loops runs (a.length)^2 times and the code inside the the last for loop runs ii.length = a.length times. So, we have (a.length)^2 + a.length iterations in total, resulting in O(a.length^2).

The amount of iterations (and as such, the complexity) only depends on the size of a, not the values in it. As such, it's the same in both best and worst case scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You complexity is `O(N^2)`

Similar problem may be solved in `O(N)` complexity if use **Hash Table**.

Answer (score 0):

The for loops are directly dependent on the length of the array `a`.

So it `O(n*n)` in all the cases.

The last for loop does not affect the complexity of the program, Since it is already `O(n*n)`